# Disconnecting socketio from client

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to build a tool which start/stops a chart display. On the client side it is displaying the chart correct, but when I click stop button, the server side function def start_chart() doesn't stop running. I tried setting up a global variable stop_flag to break the loop, but it is not updating itself. I haven't used flask or sockets before, so not able to come up with a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

app.py

```
@socketio.on('start_chart')
def start_chart():
    chart_data = []
    stop_flag = False
    last_emitted_index = 0  # Keep track of the last emitted data index

    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        if stop_flag:
            break
        timestamp = row['timestamp']
        datapoint = row['datapoint']
        if timestamp == 0:
            continue  # Skip zero timestamp
        chart_data.append({'timestamp': timestamp, 'datapoint': datapoint})
        if i > last_emitted_index:
            emit('update_chart', {'chart_data': chart_data})
            last_emitted_index = i
        socketio.sleep(1)  # Emit new data every second
        
    print("Loop Ended")

@socketio.on('stop_chart')
def stop_chart():
    emit('stop_chart') 
    global stop_flag
    stop_flag = True
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <button id="start-btn" onclick="startChart()">Start</button>
    <button id="stop-btn" onclick="stopChart()">Stop</button>
</body>
<script>
// Start the chart
    function startChart() {
        if (!isChartRunning) {
            isChartRunning = true;
            socket.emit('start_chart');
        }
    }

    // Stop the chart
    function stopChart() {
        isChartRunning = false;
        socket.emit('stop_chart');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable stop_flag is not global in your function start_chat(). Put the 'global stop_flag' before 'stop_flag = False'.